# Svn advice -- splitting a program into two parts

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd Like advice setting up a svn structure and strategy. Here's the deal.

I have one large-ish program that I want to break into two separate programs, each of which will be further developed independently. The two independent programs will run in succession, communicate via files, and together do pretty much the same job as the existing single program, but in two phases.

When this is all done, the two programs (plus a command file to run them in succession) will be the product, and the original single program will retire to pasture, though remain available for consulting should there be questions.

Right now there is just one programmer (moi) and one customer who just runs it. There will always be just one customer. Ultimately, different programmers will work on the two parts, though initially it will just be me on both. This ability for different programmers to work independently is the main reason for the split, so that's not an issue for me.

My tentative development strategy is to clone the single program twice and then morph each clone into one of the two separate parts. The two parts will share some code, structures and constants, but not much. I presumably also need a separate small codebase for the command file.

**What svn structure and strategy would folks recommend? Should I create two branches or tags off the original code, or two separate codebases? How should I structure the repo? Etc?**

Assume that the existing single program is not yet in svn (it is, but not elegantly, so I'm happy to start over).

I am pretty much an svn naif and want to keep this as simple as possible (but not simpler -- thanks Albert). Right now I sometimes using svn via Tortoise and sometimes from within JetBrains RubyMine. I'm not sure the two work very well together, so I am willing to go one way or the other. I create svn repos at my web host service, and I am happy with that, so I don't really want to switch to git.

(I looked at related questions, and none seems to quite fit my situation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create multiple projects, in one repository. The layout would look like this:

```
/
   project1/
       trunk/
          project 1 files and folders
       tags/
       branches/
   project2/
       trunk/
          project 2 files and folders
       tags/
       branches/
   project3/
       trunk/
          project 3 files and folders
       tags/
       branches/
```

I like your idea of paring down the starting codebase to create both projects. I'd do that by committing it all to one project first, then using `svn copy` to get the baseline code in the 2nd project, and going from there independently in each project.

Comment: I'm adopting this solution -- thanks. Furthermore, I may morph the first project, the single program, into the small common codebase for the two phases, after tagging, of course.

Comment: BTW, is there any reason that the above structure is recommended rather than putting the trunk at the top level of each project, without an explicit subfolder?

Comment: The "your project here" notes were for all the files and subdirectories in your project. It doesn't need to be its own folder. I think trunk belongs at the root of each project as you say.

Answer (score 2):

```
trunk/
    project1
    project2

etc
```

I think you're over thinking this :) especially if the programs are very related in terms of communications and interfaces. You'll probably want to keep them in sync as you make changes that affect both sides. You can still tag the project directories individually, whilst branching both at the same time for major changes.

Chances are you'll also end up with a project3 (or common stuff) so its a good idea to keep them close and not put them in different repositories.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts. Project2 will ultimately be further developed by an independent team. In fact, that's the rationale -- it is sensitive to the cosmetics of the customer web site, so I want that to be in their hands rather than mine. Then they also don't have to worry about the "back end". That suggests to me that Project2 have its own trunk, branches and tags. Yes, I am in effect three-tiering the monolithic codebase, or at least two-tiering.

Answer (score 1):

I like the initial plan to take the same original code-base and put it into two projects.  Add a third for the supervisor script.  If there will really be shared code, lets put that in **one place** that is accessible to the teams.  That could be the 4th project, or just let your team know that shared code goes in project y.  Your build tool can be responsible for pulling that shared part from the correct project, but please don't maintain copies of it in multiple places.

<strike>BTW: This sounds like a great opportunity to switch to git.  By using a [feature branch](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-feature-branch) or [git flow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/workflows#!workflow-gitflow) type of workflow, you should be able to more easily scale the number of developers.</strike>  <-- but I still believe this.

Comment: Too much technical expertise required to set up and maintain git. My web host handles svn for me. That's the main reason.

Comment: Thanks! But my main question is how to implement that in svn. If I make the clones branches, will there be some unforeseen issues later, considering that they are not so much branches in the end, but separate projects.

Comment: forget git, use [fossil!](https://www.fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/tip/www/index.wiki)

Comment: Branches are for things that will merge, you intend to compare to each other, may move code between them, etc.  Since you intend to fully split these and not ever merge them, go with different projects.  I don't have specific pitfalls that would help with, but (in almost all situations) using the tools as intended means you don't have to out think the developers.  You'll get the benefit of their smarts as well and you don't even have to know why :)